# Add the 'people reached' count to the API?

Tags: feature-request, api, api-v2, users

Can we have [the *people reached* statistic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/148310) added to the `/users/{ids}` method?

The response could simply be:

```
"people_reached": 1000
```

I'm asking because it would be cool to get a network-wide number.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote [the related feature-request for the SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253579/include-the-people-reached-and-helpful-flags-count-data-in-sede).

Comment: @BrockAdams Done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the feature request is approved (unlikely, and [a similar request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253579/include-the-people-reached-and-helpful-flags-count-data-in-sede) has no developer love either), you can get this number in one of 3 ways:

- You can get slightly **stale data with [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305411/is-there-a-way-to-get-people-reached-sum-across-entire-network-for-a-user)** (Not mine, and may not reflect SE's algorithm as of 2018).
  Note that it uses your Stack Exchange account number (4337810 for the OP) -- which you can get by clicking on the "Accounts" listing of any profile page.
- **Or,** You can make a **boatload of API calls** to get the current information. See the pseudocode, below.
- **Or,** You can just **scrape all of the user's account profile pages**, extracting and summing the *people reached* stat.

---

**Recipe for calculating network people reached using the API:**

1. Refer to [the formula listed in this Meta SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here).
2. Set variable `helpfulViews` to zero.
3. With the user's SE id, call `/users/{ids}/associated`.  For example:
   [/2.2/users/4337810/associated?pagesize=100&filter=!Snjr*CId4V6czluxxf](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#pagesize=100&ids=4337810&filter=!Snjr*CId4V6czluxxf&run=true)
4. Discard any returned sites that have `question_count == 0` AND `answer_count == 0`.
5. For each of the remaining site accounts:

   1. Extract the domain name from the `site_url`. This will be passed as the site parameter.
   2. Using the user's `user_id` for that site, call `/users/{ids}/questions`. For example:
      [users/74948/questions?pagesize=100&site=webapps.stackexchange.com&filter=!C%28o2zYW*Tj-xzlEqb](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/74948/questions?pagesize=100&site=webapps.stackexchange.com&filter=!C%28o2zYW*Tj-xzlEqb)
   3. Loop through the returned questions, adding the `view_count`s to `helpfulViews`. But discard any question that has `closed_date` set.
   4. Now, call `/users/{ids}/answers`. For example:
      [/users/74948/answers?pagesize=100&site=webapps.stackexchange.com&filter=!.UE8F0rlDSTV0*VE](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/74948/answers?pagesize=100&site=webapps.stackexchange.com&filter=!.UE8F0rlDSTV0*VE)
   5. Set variable `ansMetrics` to an empty array of objects.
   6. For each answer:

      1. If the score is <= 0, discard it.
      2. Otherwise, make an object containing: the `answer_id`, the `question_id`, the `score`, and the `is_accepted` value.  Add that object to the to `ansMetrics` array.
   7. Now, collect the `question_id`s, from `ansMetrics` into batches of 100.
   8. For each batch, call `/questions/{ids}`. For example:
      [/2.2/questions/65674;67758?pagesize=100&site=webapps.stackexchange.com&filter=!*l83g-Uitq5r7FkUI*AdfApf](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&ids=65674%3B67758&filter=!*l83g-Uitq5r7FkUI*AdfApf&site=webapps&run=true)
   9. For each question returned:

      1. Retrieve the associated `answer_id` from the `ansMetrics` object.
      2. If: That answer has `is_accepted` == `true`, then add the *question's* `view_count` to `helpfulViews`.
      3. Else If: That answer has `score` > `5`, then add the *question's* `view_count` to `helpfulViews`.
      4. Else If: That answer is in the top 3 answers, then add the *question's* `view_count` to `helpfulViews`.
      5. Else If: That answer has at least 20% of the total score of all answers, then add the *question's* `view_count` to `helpfulViews`.
6. When all the looping is done, `helpfulViews` will be the *people reached* score.

Comment: That [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305411/is-there-a-way-to-get-people-reached-sum-across-entire-network-for-a-user) is waaaaay off, like inflated by **1800%** for my SO "people reached".  Thus, I'm hesitant to put any time into trying your API method.  I realize this is an old question; maybe something's changed?

Comment: @ashleedawg: (1) That's about 2 logical fallacies, (2) That is not my SEDE query, as clearly shown on the SEDE page, (3) The 2 methodologies are not interlinked, (4) Yes, it is very possible that SE's method has changed. Search the meta sites.

Comment: @BrockAdams: Why https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/74948/answers?pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow.com&filter=!.UE8F0rlDSTV0*VE return no value in `items` ? I have replaced site as `stackoverflow.com`

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ : i tried to use siteName as `stackoverflow.com` in the above queries and it does not return any `item`

Comment: @ShashankVivek your query has an invalid filter: `Invalid filter specified`. You could try generating the filter string again and retrying