# How to get the "People reached" stat of a user, using the API?

Tags: support, users, api-v2.2

I checked the user ids and advanced search API docs, but I could not get this stat. Does Stack Exchange provide this info in the API?

```
/2.2/users/{ID}?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't as of now. It doesn't exist in the API.

[Here's a feature request I made](https://stackapps.com/questions/6301/add-the-people-reached-count-to-the-api) - please upvote that for higher chances of getting this added! :)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an "answer", and a hint to flag as a duplicate. ;)

Comment: @BrockAdams I wasn't allowed to - it said that question doesn't have an answer!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have checked the original question as well. Sounds like we need to approach in a round about way!! big process..